How to import a reference to a date in Excel without becoming a DateObject
The most basic example, Excel cell A1 has a date, e.g. 12/12/2023 and cell A2 has the formula =A1, that reference in A2 disappears and becomes a DateObject just as A1 after Import.
In[1]:= Import["file.xlsx"][[1]]


Out[1]:=  {{12/12/2023,12/12/2023}}

Using
In[2]:= Import["file.xlsx","Formulas"][[1]]


Out[2]:=   {{,}}

Returns an empty List where {{,=A1}} is what I would have expected as a result.
How to avoid a reference to a date in Excel becoming a DateObject when using Import["file.xlsx"]?

Which version are you using? In version 14, if I use Import["file.xlsx", "Formulas"] (note: Formulas, not Formula!), I get {{{"", "A1"}}}.

@Domen, thanks ... I corrected the "Formulas" in my question (typo, apologies). I'm using version 13.1 on MAC. Seems like something that was improved with the version upgrade.
